# Is it possible to run jpegoptim command in shell_exec php?

Tags: php, shell, terminal, image-optimization

Here in my php file, I'm trying to execute a shell command. I was able to run the command variable value in the terminal just fine. But somehow shell_exec doesn't do it for me.

```
$command = 'jpegoptim '.$imgpath;
shell_exec($command);
```

Look like 'git status' won't even work in here

```
$output = shell_exec('git status');
```

Update: finally getting an error

sh: jpegoptim: command not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to install jpegoptim on your server. After this you can use the shell_exec("jpegoptim") command.

apt-get install jpegoptim